# How does a Blazor Server App execute an onclick C# method?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I wrote a Blazor Server App which runs fine but I don't really understand the innards of execution. Have read many web articles about what Server App means but am still confused.

Imagine a web page with button that has a C# method onclick(). I assume that C# code is executed on the server? Then the question is how does the client tell the server to execute this method (over SignalR) and what does the server pass back (i.e. is it the whole page again or just bits of it?)

A Web Assembly App is a little clearer in my mind as I understand the C# actually executes on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an excellent article that answers my question, including how I can monitor the SignalR traffic!

[logging-signalr-traffic-in-server-side-blazor](https://www.appvnext.com/blog/2019/12/21/logging-signalr-traffic-in-server-side-blazor)